# Passing arguments to a pynput listener

Tags: python-2.7, parameter-passing, listener, event-listener, pynput

Im using pynput listener to catch key presses from keyboard, but the problem is that i need to pass parameter to the on_press and on_release functions and i just can't figure out how to do it.
you can see in the code, i need to pass the client socket so i could send him the key that was pressed/released.

```
def handle_keyboard_events(self, client_socket):
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_key_press, on_release=self.on_key_release)
    keyboard_listener.start()

def on_key_press(self, key):
    key_press_command = KeyPress(key)
    self.send_message(key_press_command, True, client_socket)

def on_key_release(self, key):
    key_release_command = KeyRelease(key)
    self.send_message(key_release_command, True, client_socket)
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you are using `self` so you are inside a `class`.

why dont you use `self.client_socket = client_socket` in your constructor?

```py
# update your constructor with self.client_socket
def __init__(client_socket, **other_args_of_yours):
    
    # use this object variable when you activate key listener
    self.client_socket = client_socket
```

or add `self.client_socket = client_socket` in `handle_keyboard_events()` method:

```
def handle_keyboard_events(self, client_socket):
    
    self.client_socket = client_socket # <----- update
    
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=self.on_key_press, 
        on_release=self.on_key_release
    )
    keyboard_listener.start()
```

and use `self.client_socket` in `press` and `release` methods

```py
def on_key_press(self, key):
    key_press_command = KeyPress(key)
    self.send_message(key_press_command, True, self.client_socket) # <--- update

def on_key_release(self, key):
    key_release_command = KeyRelease(key)
    self.send_message(key_release_command, True, self.client_socket) # <--- update
```

OR

if you really want to pass `client_socket` to your `press` and `release` methods, you can try this:

```py
def handle_keyboard_events(self, client_socket):
    # use lambda to pass the client socket
    # with this method, after you get the `key` you can pass additional params to on_press and on_release
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=lambda key: self.on_key_press(key, client_socket), # <--- client socket passed
        on_release=lambda key: self.on_key_release(key, client_socket) # <--- client socket passed
    )
    keyboard_listener.start()

# add client socket as new arg
def on_key_press(self, key, client_socket):
    key_press_command = KeyPress(key)
    self.send_message(key_press_command, True, client_socket) # from params
    
# add client socket as new arg
def on_key_release(self, key, client_socket):
    key_release_command = KeyRelease(key)
    self.send_message(key_release_command, True, client_socket) # from params
```

and you are ready to go.